# CucumberException failed to instanciate class

Tags: maven, class, jar, cucumber

I have this problem for 3 days now and I don't know how to solve it...
Here it is :
I am doing acceptance tests using Cucumber and Maven.

All of my tests work well and I created a jar library which I import as a dependency in the pom.xml file of my project I want to test.

Everything worked well until I just changed the name of the groupID of my jar I imported...

However, I did a "mvn install" command for my project which I want to import as a jar library before running again my project to test (and obviously I changed the dependance in my pom.xml file).

The error I am getting now is :

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class cucumber.steps.myClass
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:46)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:32)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
        ... 33 more
      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Element
        at myPackageImportFromJar.anotherClass.<clinit>
        at cucumber.steps.myClass.<init>
        ... 38 more
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.Element
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 40 more
```

Just an information (may be my error comes from that) : I am using the jar file to read properties in the project I want to test.

If you have any idea, I would be glad to hear it...
Thank you !

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28387412/1119381. It might be an issue with dependencies versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I already had seen this question and in my case I am not using anything else than cucumber-java (1.2.4), cucumber-junit(1.2.4) and junit(4.12) dependencies ...

Answer (score 0):

Found out where the problem comes from :

I was using org.jdom dependency and jdom was never recognize and could never be instantiate (a bit weird but I can't explain it...). The solution I used is changing jdom dependency to jdom2 dependency. With this dependency, everything works well (for the moment).